# Carbon Fields - Warning : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Tags: php, wordpress

На форуме много тем с этим вопросом но я для себя не решил проблему. На плагине Carbon Fields 3.0 я создал повторяющиеся поля (Repeating Groups (complex)) и внутри повторяющихся полей я создал еще повторяющиеся поля.

```
$basic_options_container = Container::make( 'theme_options', 'site_tours', 'Туры' )
->set_icon( 'dashicons-location-alt' )
->add_tab('Туры', array(
    Field::make( 'complex', 'site_tours_group', '' )
        ->set_layout( 'tabbed-horizontal' )
        ->add_fields( array(
            Field::make( 'text', 'site_tours_name', ( 'Название тура' ) )
                ->set_width( 50 ),
            Field::make( 'image', 'site_tours_photo', ( 'Изображение тура' ) ) 
            ->set_value_type( 'url' )
            ->set_width( 50 ),
            Field::make( 'complex', 'site_tours_cities', '')
                ->set_layout( 'tabbed-vertical' )
                ->add_fields( array(
                Field::make( 'text', 'site_tours_city', ('Город') ),
            ) ),
        ) ),
))
```

Вывожу таким образом:

```
   <? $tours = carbon_get_theme_option( 'site_tours_group' );
            foreach ( $tours as $tour ) {
                echo '<div class="tour">';
                    echo '<div class="tour-photo">';
                        echo '<img src="' . $tour['site_tours_photo'] . '" alt="">';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '<div class="tour-info">';
                        echo '<h4 class="tour-name">' . $tour['site_tours_name'] . '</h4>';
                        echo '<div class="tour-top-block">';
                            echo '<div class="tour-cities">';
                            $cities = carbon_get_theme_option( 'site_tours_cities' );
                                    foreach ($cities as $city) {
                                        echo '<span>' . $city['site_tours_city'] . '</span>';
                                    }

                            }
?>
```

первый цикл работает но то что внутри цикл

```
 foreach ($cities as $city) {
      echo '<span>' . $city['site_tours_city'] . '</span>';
 }
```

выводит ошибку:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Принт массива $cities

```
1
```

Принт массива $tours

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [_type] => _
        [site_tours_name] => TEST NAME
        [site_tours_photo] => http://test.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/3-min.jpg
        [site_tours_cities] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [_type] => _
                        [site_tours_city] => London
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [_type] => _
                        [site_tours_city] => New york
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [_type] => _
                        [site_tours_city] => Tokyo
                    )

            )

    )

)
```

Comment: Добрый день, что лежит в $cities?

Comment: Добрый день, текст

Comment: Это предположение или?
выполните print_r($cities); закоментив цикл, и покажите что там лежит.

Comment: Покажите этот текст. Foreach работает только с массивами и объектами, ожидаемо получить ошибку.

Comment: Странно через админку я добавил London, New york, Tokyo. но когда выполнил print_r($cities); вышло "1"

Comment: Смотрите я сейчас попробовал выполнить принт для цикла $tours там вышло мои данные которые я ввёл Array ( [0] => Array ( [_type] => _ [site_tours_name] => Oriental tales [site_tours_photo] => http://test.com/3-min.jpg [site_tours_cities] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [_type] => _ [site_tours_city] => London ) [1] => Array ( [_type] => _ [site_tours_city] => New york ) [2] => Array ( [_type] => _ [site_tours_city] => Tokyo ) ) ) ) 1

Comment: site_tours_cities - вы уверенны, что именно эта опция отвечает за это кастомное поле?

Comment: site_tours_city - вот интересующая вас опция, исходя из массива, а вы пытаетесь работать с site_tours_cities

Comment: @Dreamer добавьте в тему свой `принт для цикла $tours` чтоб было видно структуру, с форматированием, а не как эта каша, что вы кинули

Comment: @InDevX сделано)

Comment: @Dreamer вот, сразу бы так.. у вас в $tour уже всё имеется, просто через `foreach` по `$tour['site_tours_cities']` проходитесь

Comment: Написал ответ ниже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($tour['site_tours_cities'] as $city) {
    echo '<span>' . $city['site_tours_city'] . '</span>';
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: Пожалуйста. Удачи

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    foreach ($tour['site_tours_cities'] as $city){ //цикл по массиву
        echo $city['site_tours_city']; // выводим имя города
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]